# leaflet - count number of requests sent by leaflet to osm (openstreetmap)

Tags: maps, client, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm using leaflet.js for a project. Leaflet sends requests to open street map (osm) tile server to get its tiles. As these requests are sent directly from the client, I have a hard time finding about the requests on my server.

**Question:** Is there a way to find out the number of requests sent by leaflet to the tile servers at osm?

(I was not able to find any $.ajax / $.get / $.post in [leaflet.js](http://leafletjs.com/)!)

Comment: I have the same confuse. Can not find any Http request related code so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that `$.ajax` / `$.get` / `$.post` are methods from jQuery. Leaflet does not depend on jQuery.

Furthermore, there is no need for special AJAX requests to get tiles. As you know, tiles are plain images, so simple `<img src="path/to/tile" />` tags are used, adjusting the `src` attribute as necessary. The browser automatically makes the HTTP request.

Finally, the browser may serve tiles directly from its cache, decreasing the actual OSM server requests.

If you still want to monitor the count of tiles requests (remember that on client browser, you will not be able to differentiate between a server response and a browser cache), you could instrument the [`L.TileLayer.createTile`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v1.0.0-rc.2/src/layer/tile/TileLayer.js#L123-L146) or [`L.TileLayer.getTileUrl`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v1.0.0-rc.2/src/layer/tile/TileLayer.js#L148-L171) methods (like adding 1 to a global variable anytime one of those methods are executed).