# Leaflet.js: how the query of tile works in web browser

Tags: javascript, leaflet

When the Leaflet map's zoom level or center is changed, we can see that there are new tile images are requested. In browser we can confirm that in the devtools panel.

I studied the source code of the Leaflet.js library. But didn't find the code or function to send request.

I want to know the mechanism about this point. This behavior is controlled in which level. In code level or Browser level? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, how the tiles are compulted and loaded depends on the layer implemention ifself. Here we will take the `TileLayer` which extends `GridLayer` as an example:

When a layer is added to map by `Map#addLayer`([code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/Layer.js#L157)), the following methods will be called:

`Layer#_layerAdd(#172) -->Layer@onAdd(#110) --> GridLayer.js#L156 -->GridLayer@_update(#638)`

And the function `GridLayer#_update()` will caculate the required tiles according to the viewport, and send request to server.

Also the layer will listen on `move` and `zoom` events which will triggered the `GridLayer#_onMoveEnd(#621)` method, inside this function , the `_update` will be called again.

HTH.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Check the code in `GridLayer` module, and with other post's help (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38705374/leaflet-count-number-of-requests-sent-by-leaflet-to-osm-openstreetmap). I roughly figure out the mechanism. The tile is just images, so the leaflet create <img src=''> element with the src attribute. Leaflet will create the src attribute, then the browser will send the request to get the image automatically.

Comment: That's right, it just add the dom element(`img` here) to the map container.